# How do I replace all special characters with their respective hex codes?

Tags: c#, .net, vba, string

I have a XML file and it contains multiple special characters.

I want to replace all the special characters with their respective hex codes.
So `&` becomes `&#x0026` and so on. But only special characters.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` to decode special characters. More in the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode

But you cannot use this method on the whole XML string, because `<` and `>` will be replaced. So you need to apply it only on the text nodes and attributes values